# Netbeans platform and menus

Tags: java, netbeans-platform

Does anyone know how to edit the menus shown in the skeleton created by the Netbeans platform?

Thanks in advance for the time you will spend trying to help me.

Comment: Did you mean GUI Form Examples?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

*Preamble: the only way to edit menu items that are present in the platform is through one of your own modules. This means that in order to remove or rename a menu item in another module you must first add a module to your application. Your application is not itself a module but a (potential) collection of modules.*

The simplest way to edit the menus for an NB Platform based application is the following:

1. In one of your modules, expand the `Important Files` node
2. Expand the `XML Layer` node (assuming the module has a layer file¹)
3. Expand the `This layer in context` node
4. Expand the `Menu Bar` node
5. Right-click on any menu (folder node) or menu item (file node) and select `Delete`

This will add the necessary entries to your modules layer file (_hidden entry) and as long as this module is loaded these menus and menu items will not be loaded. If you want to restore an item in the future you can either remove the entry from the layer file or right-click the item and select `Restore`.

**Edit**

Here's a method for renaming a menu item:

1. Using the above technique to find the entry you want to rename
2. Right-click the node and select "Go to Declaration"
3. Look for the attribute with a `name` of "SystemFileSystem.localizingBundle"
4. Open the application's branding interface (right-click on your application's node and select `Branding...`)
5. Choose the `Resource Bundles` tab
6. Look for the Bundle node that has the value you found in step 3

The name of the menu item will be located in this Bundle's node. Just edit this and it will be changed in your application. The key here is to locate the Bundle that the menu item is named in.

Here's a method for replacing a menu item's action:

1. Follow steps 1 and 2 from the previous outline
2. Once you've gotten to the declaration, search (Ctrl + F) the same file for the `originalFile` value (you're only looking for the `.instance` declaration)²
3. Once you've found where the action is defined, copy the structure to your layer file
4. Using the `delegate` attribute you can redefine what action is used for this menu item

The point here is to override the menu item's action definition in your layer file, replacing the action with your own. You can also use this technique to override the display name of the action but the Branding technique is simpler if you don't need to replace the action as well.

---

¹If your module doesn't have a layer file you'll need to create one before you can use this technique. This requires that you create a `layer.xml` file in one of your module's packages. Then you need to register this file in your Modules Manifest file using the following `OpenIDE-Module-Layer: com/example/mymodule/layer.xml`

²For this step you can highlight the `.instance` name of the `originalValue` attribute's value and press Ctrl + F. For example, if the `originalValue` attribute's value is `Actions/Window/org-netbeans-core-windows-actions-RecentViewListAction.instance` you want to highlight only the `org-netbeans-core-windows-actions-RecentViewListAction.instance` part. The point here is to find where the action is defined (this part of the layer file is only adding the action to the menu).

Comment: But how can I edit an already loaded menus, which is part of the skeleton (the "navigate" menu for instance)?

Comment: What do you mean by edit? Do you want to rename it or add an item to it?

Comment: See my edit for a description of how to rename a menu item or replace its action. The first description I gave is how to suppress it, if by suppress you mean remove it from the menu

Comment: Your explanation seems detailed and answers a big part of my question. But one non solved case remains : if you start a new application based on the Netbeans platform, you get a working application which comes with it's own menus. And I can't see anything in what you wrote which explains neither how to remove these menus nor to change the entry menu's linked code. Have I missed something?

Comment: OK, I have got your point. But it is a little bit confusing to have to create a module to edit or delete menus that were present before the creation of the module!!

Comment: I agree that it is a bit confusing. The menus that are present are part of other modules that are included with the base platform. For example, the `org-netbeans-core-windows-actions-RecentViewListAction` that I used as an example is part of the core-windows module. So, there are other modules that are already contributing to the menu system before you add your own module.

Comment: @Jonathan Spooner Thanks, I've spent hours trying to find this!

Answer (score 5):

In addition to what has been nicely explained above, here is a simple trick to add your own global menu item without even looking to the XML file content:

1. In your module tree go and find the file named **layers.xml**
2. click on the **layers.xml** node to unfold its children, these are two folders:

   - **this layer**
   - **this layer in context**
3. unfold the "**this layer in context**" node and go to the sub-folder **Menu Bar**
4. right click and add a new folder (name it **History** e.g) inside **Menu Bar**. The name of this new folder will be used as a category in the global menus of you main GUI window.
5. To add a sub menu item to this global menu, right click on your module, choose ***new->action*** action and when asked to select the menu to place this sub menu in, choose **History**.

PS: you can also add a category to the **Toolbar** as you did for the **Menu Bar**.
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what exactly you want to do, but the layer.xml file is usually the place to do such changes.

Comment: I have a maven version that doesn't have a layer.xml file. If this is the case do i need to add a layer.xml file and where would i add it? FYI i'm using the maven version of the NBP.